# Trying to edit PCDATA in an XML document

Tags: xml, perl

One of our processes includes a copy-paste from an Excel spreadsheet into an Oxygen editor document. It works pretty well, but doesn't catch special characters, so, I'm writing a script to find and change them. I've started with XML::Parser in stream mode, but I'm not so sure I'm going to get where I need to go with this approach.

For one thing, because the parser (correctly) does not care about attribute order, the attributes can (and do) come back in a different order, which will annoy some folks. Also, I'm not currently able to consistently identify the PCDATA. And it seems a little bit much to have to re-assemble the element tags...and I'm not really going to handle EMPTY elements very well, either. Am I missing just a little bit here, or should I look at something else, like XML::Twig?

Thanks in advance to all (anyone) who take(s) the time to reply!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use XML::Parser;

my $xml = <<EOD;
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <from id="t_8ur9k0" type="king">Maximus</from>
    <to>knave</to>
    <subject>My boots</subject>
    <body>I <i>really</i> want my riding boots. Bring them to me, at once!</body>
  </message>
</messages>
EOD

my $parser = new XML::Parser(Style => 'Stream', ErrorContext => 2);
$parser->setHandlers(Start => \&handle_start, 
      End => \&handle_end, 
      Char => \&handle_char,
      Default => \&handle_default);

$parser->parse($xml);

sub handle_start {
  my ($self, $tag, %attrs) = @_;
  my $atts = '';
  if (%attrs) {
    while ( my ($key, $val) = each(%attrs) ) {
      $atts .= " " . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
    }
  }
  print "<" . $tag . $atts . ">";
}

sub handle_end {
  my ($self, $tag) = @_;
  print "</" . $tag . ">";
}

sub handle_char {
  my ($self,$raw) = @_;
  if ( !($raw =~ m/\s/) ) {
    $raw =~ s/.*/FOO/;
  }
  print $raw;
}

sub handle_default {
  my ($self,$str) = @_;
  print $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XML::Parser` supplies the attribute information to the `Start` callback handler in the correct order. The attributes are appearing out of sequence in your program because you are putting them into a hash in the line

```
my ($self, $tag, %attrs) = @_;
```

which loses the ordering.

`XML::Parser` is rarely used on its own. You can use `XML::Twig`, but my preference is [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML).

You don't say what transformations you want to do on the data, but this program reproduces the input apart from the (arbitrarily chosen) `<subject>` element which it deletes. Note the straightforward use of XPath notation to manipulate the document, and the `<from>` element's multiple attributes which are kept in order.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<XML);
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <from id="t_8ur9k0" type="king" b="b" c="c" d="d" e="e" f="f" g="g">Maximus </from>
    <to>knave</to>
    <subject>My boots</subject>
    <body>I <i>really</i> want my riding boots. Bring them to me, at once!</body>
  </message>
</messages>
XML

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('/messages/message/subject');
$nodes[0]->unbindNode;
print $doc->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <from id="t_8ur9k0" type="king" b="b" c="c" d="d" e="e" f="f" g="g">Maximus </from>
    <to>knave</to>

    <body>I <i>really</i> want my riding boots. Bring them to me, at once!</body>
  </message>
</messages>
```

---

**UPDATE**

This is a demonstration of modifying all text nodes regardless of the structure of the document

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<XML);
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <from id="t_8ur9k0" type="king" b="b" c="c" d="d" e="e" f="f" g="g">Maximus </from>
    <to>knave</to>
    <subject>My boots</subject>
    <body>I <i>really</i> want my riding boots. Bring them to me, at once!</body>
  </message>
</messages>
XML

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('//text()');
$_->setData(lc $_->data) for @nodes;
print $doc->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <message>
    <from id="t_8ur9k0" type="king" b="b" c="c" d="d" e="e" f="f" g="g">maximus </from>
    <to>knave</to>
    <subject>my boots</subject>
    <body>i <i>really</i> want my riding boots. bring them to me, at once!</body>
  </message>
</messages>
```

Comment: Ah, OK. As I recall, XML parsers are not required to honor attribute order, so I figured that's what was tossing them. Hashes do the same. And apologies for not being clear in what I'm after: I want to scan the content of PCDATA elements and change special characters to entities; for example, change each [±] to [&#177;]. So XPath would be unmaintainable, requiring me to update the script every time I change the DTD.

Comment: @Greg: I don't see the problem. You can access all the PCDATA in an XML document using `//text()`. I have added to my answer to show how you could set all text nodes to lower case.

Comment: I do -- I declared XPath incapable of helping me before looking at it again. (It's been years since I studied and used it.) My apologies for the bother!

Comment: @Greg: no problem. But I'm not clear what *I do* means. Are you OK with XPath or do you still need help?

Comment: I meant, I understand that the problem is that I didn't research the problem thoroughly, which would have led me to understand that XPath could in fact select all elements containing text/PCDATA. I'll just sit down with a good XPath reference and refresh my memory. Thanks so much for this extra follow-up!